# Query Relational data on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I have seen the other questions relating to querying relational data on parse and they don't quite meet my need.

I have 3 related classes: `Teacher (1->many) Course (many<-1) Category`

Given the above structure, I want to query for all Instructors who have courses that fall under a certain category. Here is what I have so far:

```
    var Category = Parse.Object.extend("Category");
    var category = new Category();
    category.id = "shdh43ay";

    var Course = Parse.Object.extend("Course"); //There are pointers on Course to both Teacher and Category
    var courseQuery = new Parse.Query(Course);
    courseQuery.equals('Category', category);


    var Teacher = Parse.Object.extend("Teacher");
    var teacherQuery = new Parse.Query(Teacher);
    teacherQuery.matchesQuery(); //Here is where I am stuck
```

It doesn't look to me like a matchesQuery would do the trick, any ideas would be welcome

Comment: If there is a pointer from a course to a teacher, then you can use `include` to get the teacher information at the same time in your `courseQuery `

Comment: Yeah that's what I have had to do since posting this question, the problem is I then have duplicates which I have to sort out